# Вводное или не вводное выражение "тем не менее"?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Может ли *тем не менее* выступать в качестве вводного выражения?

Answer (score 1):

> Может ли ***тем не менее*** выступать в качестве вводного выражения?

.

Чаще тем ***не менее*** употребляется в функции частицы или союза, читается без интонационного выделения и не обособляется.  Примеры см. в [***"Справочнике по пунктуации"  на Грамоте.ру.***](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_731)

Реже  —  в функции вводного. Вот что написано по этому поводу в ***"Словаре вводных слов, сочетаний и предложений" О.А. Остроумовой и О.Д. Фрамоль:***

> Редко употребляется в функции вводного для выражения субъективного
>   отношения к какому-либо факту, **только при интонационном
>   подчёркивании**:
>
> *Мы, мол, всё понимаем, но, **тем не менее,** должны проявлять вежливость* (В. Шукшин);
>
> *Опять же полностью согласен. **Тем не менее**, какие ваши планы?* (С. Довлатов);
>
> *Большинство же, пройдя искус поэзии, более к ней никогда не обращалось, кроме как в качестве читателей, сохраняя, **тем не
>   менее**, глубокую признательность за уроки лаконизма и гармонии, у неё
>   полученные* (И. Бродский).

Answer (score 1):

В словаре "Трудные случаи русской пунктуации" (Пахомов В.М.  и др.) "тем не менее" называется **частицей или союзом, которые не обособляются**.И всё-таки обособленные варианты встречаются, поэтому **попробуем обобщить материал.**

1) Есть случаи, когда **обособление требуется в обязательном порядке или просто очень желательно**, так как "тем не менее" плохо  стыкуется с последующим текстом, например перед местоимением "какой":

Тем не менее, **какие** бы чувства ни лежали в основе моралистических рассуждений, эти настроения вполне реальны и постоянно обновляются. Также: Тем не менее, **именно** тусующаяся молодёжь ―  один из наиболее перспективных рынков сбыта для качественных  напитков.

2) Если "тем не менее" находится **в начале предложения** (особенно нераспространенного), то его обособление кажется необоснованным (можно заменить союзами **НО, ОДНАКО**), например: **Тем не менее**, их позиция не из лёгких: у белых есть ясный план атаки (здесь обособление нежелательно).

3) **В середине предложения обособление факультативно,** оно является авторским и делается для интонационного выделения и подчеркивания этого выражения: Но меня, **тем не менее**, волновала именно тема кризиса художника.

4) Обычно **нет обособления в начале предложения перед союзами НО, И**: Но тем не менее начало важному государственному делу было положено.И тем не менее вы разработали метод, который позволяет бороться с микробами.

**И общий итог:** Обособление "тем не менее"  особенно тесно связано со структурой предложения и интонацией и практически **соответствует не грамматическому, а в большей степени интонационному принципу** русской пунктуации.

Answer (score 0):

Выражение "тем не менее" может выступать в роли союза в значении "но, однако". Тогда оно выделяется запятыми. Но выделяется не сам оборот, а вся конструкция с этим оборотом: "Он и так был хорошим фехтовальщиком, тем не менее тренировался каждый день".

Comment: Так же,как союз "однако" может употребляться в роли вводного слова, если стоит в середине или в конце предложения, так и "тем не менее" ("Я, тем не менее, не согласен с Вами")